# We have a static Hugo website and we want to migrate it to Wordpress

Tags: migration, cms

We have many static generated sites using Hugo and we want to migrate them all to a Wordpress CMS. Does anyone know how to convert markdown to wordpress data?

Comment: Hello & Welcome to The WordPress Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, this question is too broad of a question for this exchange. There may be many different and varied ways to migrate static Hugo content and/or convert markdown to a WordPress friendly data format. A better place to ask and discuss this kind of question may be [The Official WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forum/wp-advanced/). For more information please [take The Tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [Help Section](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Just my two cents, but I don't see that as too broad or inappropriate. And in my experience the official WordPress forums rarely have the technical depth or breadth of experience found here on StackExchange as most people who answer in that forum are end-users, not developers. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [postmark extension](https://github.com/dirtsimple/postmark) for `wp-cli` to create posts from markdown files with quite a bit of control over how you deal with your frontmatter.

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-markdown/ but it only allows you to upload one file at a time. It does now do a batch migration. I think I will try and connect to this developer. But will leave this post in here if anyone comes across a better solution. Blessings